# Cannot find -lusb when building ni package!

Tags: openni, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
When i run "rosmake ni". the following error appears:
Linking CXX executable ../bin/openni_example
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Please help me fix it. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9311/cannot-find--lusb-when-building-ni-package!/) by [nhanndt](https://answers.ros.org/users/249/nhanndt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-06**:
What is the output of `rosdep satisfy ni`?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-06**:
What OS are you on? Which version of ROS (Cturtle/Diamondback/Unstable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

okay, here's a solution, after trying the above mentioned approaches I still had the same problem but I finally figured it out.

> Open *System->Administration->Synaptic
> manager*, search libusb and then
> select
> *libusb-1.0-0-dev, libusb++-0.1-4c2* for
> installation.

and rerun rosmake ni --rosdep-install. It works perfectly
if it doesn't work then for reference I have the following lib-usb* packages installed
libhpmud0,libusb-0.1-4,libusb-1.0-0,libusb-dev,libusb-1.0-0-dev, libusb++-0.1-4c2,libusbsr,libftdi1,libusbmuxd1.

Make sure you have these and if you still have a problem then let me know

Best,
CV

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-07**:
cool... if you want you can accept this answer by checking the tick mark.

**Comment by [nhanndt](https://answers.ros.org/users/249/nhanndt/) on 2011-03-07**:
Thanks bro! I fixed it by running this command: " sudo apt-get install libusb -1.0-0-dev libusb-dev".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears libusb is not installed. Try running `rosmake --rosdep-install ni` and allow it to install any required dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1